# Android - How to upload photo from the SD card to the Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

I use the Facebook Android SDK.

## Goal

Create multiple posts in news feed of Facebook logged in user that will contain photo from the Android device (its [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital)) and some comment. The result should be the same as when you do it using the Add photo/video feature directly in Facebook. In the end, it should look like this:

### Wanted Facebook result

[image: Goal]

### Problem

**I can't do it.**

I went through the numerous similar posts on Stack Overflow, but no answer there so far.

## What I have tried to implement so far

### Approach 1: SD card photos 2 Facebook album

#### How

Upload pictures from my mobile (its SD card) to an album that is created for my application the first time I upload a picture from it. In this case, when constructing the params object, I use the `picture` key and put the bytes of the picture as its value. I use `me/photos` in the `request(...)` call of the Facebook (or AsyncFacebookRunner) object. **

#### The problem

Not all uploaded images are displayed on my wall. Instead, there is something like *x photos were added to the album xxx*.

#### The code snippet is this (for one picture)

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Uploaded on " + now());
params.putByteArray("picture", bytes); //bytes contains photo bytes, no problem here
asyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PostPhotoRequestListener(), null);
```

#### Facebook result

[image: Photos to album]

### Approach 2: Internet photos 2 facebook news feed

#### How

Display pictures stored somewhere on the Internet in posts on my wall. In this case, when constructing the params object, I use the `link` key and set the url to picture as its value. I use `me/feed` in the `request(...)` call.

#### The problem

This produces some strange output, but it isn't what I want.

#### The code snippet is this (for one picture)

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Uploaded on " + now());
params.putString("link", "http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k538/tom_rada/bota2.jpg");
asyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new PostPhotoRequestListener(), null);
```

#### Facebook result

[image: Linked photos]

### Approach 3: Mix of approach 1 and 2

#### How

I try to use the `picture` key and set photo *bytes* as its value (as in 1.), and call the request with `me/feed` (as in 2.),

#### The problem

Message is produced as I would like it to be, but no photo is included

#### The code snippet is this (for one picture)

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Uploaded on " + now());
params.putByteArray("picture", bytes); //bytes contains photo bytes, no problem here
asyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new PostPhotoRequestListener(), null);
```

#### Facebook result

[image: Almost there]

## So, any ideas how I could reach my goal?

## EDIT - WORKAROUND FOUND

It seems that the only way to create new posts containing photos on user's wall is to add photos and related comments to user's *Wall photos* album.

### How - Code snippet

**Beware: The `facebook.request` call should be replaced with async call, so the operation doesn't block the UI thread !!!**

```
String wallAlbumID = null;
String response = facebook.request("me/albums");
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
JSONArray albums = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i =0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
    if (album.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("wall")) {
        wallAlbumID = album.getString("id");
        Log.d("JSON", wallAlbumID);
        break;
    }
}
```

... and then

```
if (wallAlbumID != null) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Uploaded on " + now());
    params.putByteArray("source", bytes);
    asyncRunner.request(wallAlbumID+"/photos", params, "POST", new PostPhotoRequestListener(), null);
}
```

Comment: what is PostPhotoRequestListener? Thanks

Comment: facebook.request("me/albums"); gives an error i.e com.facebook.android.FacebookError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.  how do i get rid of this.

Comment: @varunbhardwaj: You might consider starting your own thread for your question. Even it is similar to this one here. It gives you a better chance of finding a solution.

Comment: please can you give me a link through which i can develop same app.. want to upload photos through facebook from my app.. I am not getting idea how to do it.. please any help

Comment: the workaround has a catch - it assumes user already has posted some photos to her wall sometime in the past. It will fail if there are no wall photos.

Answer (score 1):

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("your appid");

  private void uploadImage() 
        {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

            facebook.authorize(FacebookActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() 
            {                     
                @Override                     
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
                {
                   //uploadImageOnlyToWall(data, "Uploading Image only to wall","Test Post from Android while uploading photo with message");   

                    uploadImageToWallAndAlbums(imageUrl, "Image via link");

                }   

                @Override                     
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, "FaceBook Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                      
                @Override                     
                public void onError(DialogError e) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                      
                @Override                     
                public void onCancel() 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }           
            }); 

        }


       private void uploadImageOnlyToAlbum(byte[] byteArray,String caption) 
           {
               Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
               params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);  
               params.putString("caption",caption);  
               AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook); 
               mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);             
            }

           private void uploadImageToWallAndAlbums(byte[] byteArray,String caption) 
           {
               Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
               params.putString("method", "photos.upload"); 
               params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);  
               params.putString("caption", caption);  
               AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook); 
               mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);            
            }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your way of asking question and explaining where you are getting error :)

Comment: What is SampleUploadListener() ?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has not previously posted a photo on his/her wall (there is no wall photo album), you can use `me/photo` request to post a photo first. This will automatically create a wall album.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question

Answer (score 0):

```
      Facebook facebook = new Facebook("your App_id");

        private void uploadImage() 

   {

 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        final byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

        facebook.authorize(FacebookActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() 
        {                     
            @Override                     
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
            {
               //uploadImageOnlyToWall(data, "Uploading Image only to wall","Test Post from Android while uploading photo with message");   

                uploadImageToWallAndAlbums(imageUrl, "Image via link");

            }   

            @Override                     
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, " Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }                      
            @Override                     
            public void onError(DialogError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }                      
            @Override                     
            public void onCancel() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }           
        }); 

    }


   private void uploadImageOnlyToAlbum(byte[] byteArray,String caption) 
       {
           Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
           params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);  
           params.putString("caption",caption);  
           AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook); 
           mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);             
        }

       private void uploadImageToWallAndAlbums(byte[] byteArray,String caption) 
       {
           Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
           params.putString("method", "photos.upload"); 
           params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);  
           params.putString("caption", caption);  
           AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook); 
           mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);            
        }
```

Comment: when i debug my project its not reading onComplete and i am not able to post i want to post image by sdcard and text also. can u help plz

Answer (score 0):

Add this class on your code

```
public class SampleUploadListener implements RequestListener{

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onMalformedURLException *******************");
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onIOException *******************");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onFileNotFoundException *******************");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onFacebookError *******************");
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onComplete *******************");
    }

}
```