# Upload photos to Facebook wall/album from Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have downloaded the Facebook Android SDK from [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and followed the steps as in [developers.facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/) and got an application ID and run some sample code. I can post status on the wall. Now I am trying to upload a photo on the wall with a description or caption, but I can't. I browsed and mostly I found the following code as answer for photo-upload.

```
public void postImageonWall() {
    byte[] data = null;

    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/cutedog.jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    params.putString("caption", "So Cuuteee!!");
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
}
```

For this, I got the response as
    {"pid":"100003180585600_320223","aid":"100003180585600_43760","owner":100003180585600,"src":"http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/533575_198930480222970_100003180585600_320223_995139351_s.jpg","src_big":"http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/533575_198930480222970_100003180585600_320223_995139351_n.jpg","src_small":"http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/533575_198930480222970_100003180585600_320223_995139351_t.jpg","link":"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=198930480222970&set=a.198930373556314.43760.100003180585600&type=1","caption":"So Cuuteee!!","created":1333718624,"object_id":198930480222970}

The photo is uploaded somewhere (it gives some URL) as a small size picture. But not on the Facebook wall or Album. By seeing Stack Overflow question *[Android - How to upload photo from the SD card to the Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662460)*, I tried

```
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

and

```
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

For both, I got the following as response

```
   {"error":{"message":"Unsupported method, photos.upload","type":"Exception"}}
```

How do I upload on the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the source code at `https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android`.

It contains source code on how to upload an image.

Comment: Thanks Rstar..I can upload using that example but when i tried as seperate project(my own)i can't add the com_facebook_android as library project,When i add it didnt take..it just showing the cross mark.any idea please..

Answer (score 3):

Does your application have the permission `photo_upload` to upload photo to Facebook?

Try this code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");

FileInputStream in;
BufferedInputStream buf;
try {
    File file = new File("/sdcard/cutedog.jpg");

    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    buf = new BufferedInputStream(in,1070);

    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
    buf.read(bMapArray);
    params.putByteArray("picture", bMapArray);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

Comment: :"permission" means in <uses-permission> or anything in registering the app??

Comment: Where is SampleUploadListener class?