# Get album ID from facebook android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, image

i found this answer:

[fetch photos from facebook album in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706678/fetch-photos-from-facebook-album-in-android)

but i want to know how to get the ALBUM_ID?? specifically for the "wall photos" album.

Comment: That question shows you the answer; request the user's list of albums and loop through them until you find the one called 'Wall photos'

Comment: @Igy Could you please give a sample code for looping through the albums? I'm having a really bad time trying to deal with that. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working thanks to this post: [Android - How to upload photo from the SD card to the Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662460/android-app-how-to-upload-photo-from-sdcard-to-facebook-wall)

this is the code i used:

```
String wallAlbumID = null;
String response = facebook.request("me/albums");
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
JSONArray albums = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i =0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);                     
    if (album.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("wall")) {
        wallAlbumID = album.getString("id");
        Log.d("JSON", wallAlbumID);
        break;
    }
}
```

I implemented it differently though, but this is the way to go. (Y)

Comment: Good find. Might be of use to me too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have already made a call to the Graph API as the solution to the link in the OP, why not do a simple for loop? My implementation might of course be different from yours, but something like this should do it for you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < JAAlbums.length(); i++) {
    json_data = JAAlbums.getJSONObject(i);
    // Log.d("json_data", json_data.toString());

    if (json_data.has("name"))  {
        String getAlbumCoverName = json_data.getString("name");
        if (getAlbumCoverName.equals("Wall Photos"))    {
            String getAlbumID = json_data.getString("id");
        }
    }
}
```

This bit of code, in a slightly implementation always does it for me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried the code but I'm getting an error: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {"data":......

Comment: Oh. You posted while I was typing a comment. Glad you have it working there fella. ;-)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond i really appreciate it, i got it working, see my answer.